# Serilog.Sinks.Postgresql: Read configuration from appsettings.json

Tags: json, postgresql, asp.net-core, configuration, serilog

Has `Serilog.Sinks.PostgreSQL` sink got its own configuration in asppsettings.json?

Something like this:

```
"Serilog": {
...
"WriteTo": [
{
    "Name": "PostgreSQL",
    "Args": {
        "connectionStringName": "Default",
        "tableName": "Log",
        ...
        "columnOptions": [
            {
                ...
            }
       ]
     }
 },
 ...
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use `Serilog.Settings.Configuration` to add your own configuration from there.
There is a good example here: [github of seriog app-setting](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-settings-configuration/blob/dev/sample/Sample/Program.cs)

I guess in your case it would look something like:

```
 var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddJsonFile(path: "appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
                .Build();

            var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)
                .CreateLogger();
```

When your config will look something like:

```
{
  "Serilog": {
    "Using":  ["Serilog.Sinks.Postgresql"],
    "MinimumLevel": "Debug",
    "WriteTo": [
      { "Name": "Console" },
      { "Name": "File", "Args": { "path": "%TEMP%\\Logs\\serilog-configuration-sample.txt" } }
    ],
    "Enrich": ["FromLogContext", "WithMachineName", "WithThreadId"],
    "Destructure": [
      { "Name": "With", "Args": { "policy": "Sample.CustomPolicy, Sample" } },
      { "Name": "ToMaximumDepth", "Args": { "maximumDestructuringDepth": 4 } },
      { "Name": "ToMaximumStringLength", "Args": { "maximumStringLength": 100 } },
      { "Name": "ToMaximumCollectionCount", "Args": { "maximumCollectionCount": 10 } }
    ],
    "Properties": {
        "Application": "Sample"
    }
  }
}
```

You can get more information here [gitub of Serilog setting](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-settings-configuration)

Comment: I´m sorry but there is no line of code about Postgresql's sink settings in your config! 
Please have a look at my fictional config above and try rewrite it to the true syntax, if any.

Comment: "Using":  ["Serilog.Sinks.Postgresql"],

Comment: Oh boy! The most important - examples of settings for columns, is missing.

Comment: I gave you an example from the github readme because you didn't ask me to tell you how to your the config. I tried to show you what you were missing and that is possible to get your config from asppsettings.json - i wrote that it would look something like...I wrote for a general config because you didn't really share yours